# Docker container can not find file which created inside of the container

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, dockerfile

I am using C# to create 2 text files in my script as it follows:

```
       TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(getProjectDirectory() + "/data.txt",true);
       TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter(getProjectDirectory() + "/data2.txt", true);
               
        string data1 = getProjectDirectory() + "/data.txt";
        string data2= getProjectDirectory() + "/data2.txt";

        addAttachmentInput.SendKeys(data1);
        addAttachmentInput.SendKeys(data2);
```

It`s failing on             addAttachmentInput.SendKeys(data1);
as it can not find the .txt file inside the container it just created!
Here is the stack trace:
Error Message:
dotnet6sdk_1  |    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverArgumentException : invalid argument: File not found : /src/TestProject/data.txt

What I am trying to do here is to upload an attachment to the website, however docker container can not find the while where its created inside... Any ideas??

Comment: Can you share the docker file?
You should try to exec into your container and find where the file is exactly.

`docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the docker file?
You should try to exec into your container and find where the file is exactly.

`docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash`

Comment: This isn't on its own an answer to the question, and would be better left as a comment.